# Using the MediaPicker property editor in custom property (Umbraco)

Tags: angularjs, properties, editor, umbraco, media

I want to create a custom property editor, that makes use of the media picker. Right now my controller looks like this:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("My.MediaCropperController",
    function($scope, dialogService) {
        $scope.mediaPicker = {
            view: 'mediapicker',
            value: null, // or your value
            config: { disableFolderSelect: true, onlyImages: true }
        };
    });
```

And my view looks like this:

```
<umb-editor ng-controller="My.MediaCropperController" model="mediaPicker" ng-if="mediaPicker">

</umb-editor>
```

As I understand it, I need to create config object for built-in editors, then use  in the template to show the editor. However when i bring my property editor into my backoffice, nothing is being shown. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my package manifest file:

```
{   
    //you can define multiple editors   
    propertyEditors: [      
        {
            /*this must be a unique alias*/ 
            alias: "My.MediaCropper",
            /*the name*/
            name: "My Media Cropper",
            /*the html file we will load for the editor*/
            editor: {
                view: "~/App_Plugins/MediaCropper/mediacropper.html"
            }
        }
    ]
    ,
    //array of files we want to inject into the application on app_start
    javascript: [
        '~/App_Plugins/MediaCropper/mediacropper.controller.js'
    ]
}
```

Comment: your code seem fine to me, are you seeing any error in F12 developer console?

Comment: I am getting this error multiple times in my developer console. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer"

Comment: it may be you have script else where which cause this part not functioning correctly, can you locate where the error is coming from?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't reference any specific place in the code where the error occurs. Could it be that I am missing something in my HTML?

Answer (score 0):

dialogService.mediaPicker rather than $scope.mediapicker ?
May be what is causing your error, just from comparing my script to yours.